# How to pass userInfo in NSNotification?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am trying to send some data using NSNotification but get stuck. Here is my code:

```
// Posting Notification
NSDictionary *orientationData;
if(iFromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    orientationData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Right"
                                                  forKey:@"Orientation"];
}

NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[notificationCenter postNotificationName:@"Abhinav"
                                  object:nil
                                userInfo:orientationData];

// Adding observer
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(orientationChanged)
                                             name:@"Abhinav"
                                           object:nil];
```

Now how to fetch this userInfo dictionary in my selector *orientationChanged*?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You get an NSNotification object passed to your function. This includes the name, object and user info that you provided to the NSNotificationCenter.

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
}
```

Comment: Ok. And how to do this? Is it like: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:self) name:@"Abhinav" object:nil];?

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"Abhinav" object:nil];

Comment: Any reason why one may be ending up with a nil dictionary?

Comment: @NYCTechEngineer Because no user info has been provided

Comment: @JustSid That's what I thought, but I ran the debugger, and saw that a dictionary was being passed as a parameter during the post. But on the receiving method, when I try to extract userInfo, nothing.

Answer (score 23):

Your selector must have `:` to accept parameters.
e.g.

```
@selector(orientationChanged:)
```

then in the method declaration it can accept the `NSNotification` parameter.

Answer (score 6):

You are posting the notification correctly.
Please modify the Notification Observer like following.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
 name:@"Abhinav" object:nil];

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
}
```

I hope, this solution will work for you..

Answer (score 0):

In swift
To get userinfo object

```
     let dict = notification.userInfo
     print(dict)
```